# Scraping with beautifulsoup and iterating through several pages with 2 parameters changing in url

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape several pages with beautifulsoup. However, there is two parameters changing in the url.

I've tried this code with no luck so far.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

base_url= "https://superstats.dk/"
     n = 8
      for i in range(1, n+1):
       if (i == 1):
       # handle first page
    response = urlopen(base_url)
    response = urlopen(base_url + "program?aar=201" % i)
    response_plus =urlopen(response + "%2F201" % i+1)
    data = response_plus.read()
```

This is the output I wanted to iterate over several pages.

```
 import requests 
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

  r = requests.get('https://superstats.dk/program?aar=2018%2F2019')
  bs=BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

  table_div=bs.find(id="content")
  rows = table_div.find_all('tr')
  for row in rows:
     cols=row.find_all('td')
     cols=[x.text.strip() for x in cols]
     print (cols)
```

Comment: Can you please clarify your issue and expect output? It is not very clear from your question where you are facing issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `format()` function to change the value of two parameters.

```
for i in range(1,9):
  url='https://superstats.dk/program?aar=201{}%2F201{}'.format(i,i+1)
  print(url)
```

Hope this will helps.